# Is it possible to dedicate a specific network connection only to the applications?

Tags: networking

The environment where I work has an application which is available only within the intranet. Meaning it can be accessed using LAN and web access is under some restrictions with proxy server.

To avoid this restriction I use a 3G dongle but in that case I can not access that application even though I am connected to LAN.

How can I make sure web surfing with the 3G dongle and application access with LAN at the same time?

In other words is it possible to dedicate network connection to the applications?

Comment: A 3G dongle physically connected to machine and a LAN cable which is also connected to machine.
I have two network listed out in this case 
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:(office LAN)
PPP adapter airtel:(USB dongle)

Comment: Related question(and possibly a duplicate): http://superuser.com/q/398680/397839

Comment: Very related: [Toggling between two internet connections](http://superuser.com/questions/895691/toggling-between-two-internet-connections)

Answer (score 0):

It should work if the routing table is set properly.

### Some background

The routing table is a table in computers and routers that they use to determine which gateway a given packet will pass before reaching the destination. Each entry in the routing table normally specifics a subnetwork and a gateway to which the packets to this subnetwork will be sent to. There's also default route, which is used when no other entries match. A gateway is only used when the destination is not in the same subnetwork, otherwise, the packet can be sent directly.

How to change the routing table depends on what operating system you are using, but generally, the `route` command in the command line can be used.

### Your case

In your case, I suspect the hosts your application access are not in the same subnetwork(although in the same intranet) as you, and a gateway is used to access them. (If it is not the case, it should work seamlessly even when the dongle is used.) So, to tell the computer to use this gateway, you will add an entry into the routing table. The subnetwork specified in the entry will be the one the application accesses(to get it, you have to know the IP address of the hosts), and the gateway specified will be the same as the default gateway of the LAN.